# iOS How to differentiate between changes to underlying data from outside vs from within the class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, observer-pattern

I am having a conceptual issue which I am not sure there is a solution for - tracing the origin of data change.

For example, in my app I have a preferences class that writes settings to user defaults, and I have set up a custom observer pattern where any class interested in a change to settings subscribes as an observer, and is notified when the setting changes. Now, if a setting changes online or on another device, the app receives the change, saves it and notifies all observers.

If I make the change within the app by going into the settings and selecting a new value, the settings class receives the change and again notifies all observers.

The problem is, that the way one would handle the change changes based on whether is the change within the class or elsewhere.

For example, let's say I let the user pick languages they would like to support. This is done through a `UITableView` where the user can add/remove/reorder the languages. The class that handles this is subscribed as an observer of changes to the `languages` property of settings, so that if I am in the page and data is changed online, the table view gets reloaded and new languages are displayed. However, when I drag the languages into a new order, I save the new order, this fires the change event of which the class is an observer, and so the table view reloads, cutting short the animation of the drag.

In short, when receiving the observer event, I would like to be able to know whether has this change been handled already (such as if it's internal and so I already dragged/inserted/removed a row) or it requires a table view reload.

Is there any pattern, concept or method that I am unaware of which addresses this?

(By the way I am writing this in Swift 4 for a universal iOS app if that makes any difference)

Thanks

Comment: i would compare the new data state with the current data state and only reload the table if there was a change.

Comment: Thank you Paul, that could work, as long as the class keeps a local version of the data. My current set up populates the table view by getting data from the preferences class, and as the notification fires when the preferences class changes, there is no "current" or old data to compare the new version to. I guess I will have to keep a local copy of the data.